# How to do a one to many relationship in UML with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, uml

I am trying to do something of the form:
[alt text http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/4317/eswdbetcywhxebxvnhyqhzb.png](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/4317/eswdbetcywhxebxvnhyqhzb.png)

Is it possible at all to do it? I want to have a collection of Food objects in my MealEvent class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, the UML class diagram lets you set the **Multiplicity** property on **First Role** and **Second Role** properties of the relationship.

For more information, see [Properties of Associations in UML Diagrams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323862%28VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Argh. I'm using Professional. No luck then?

Answer (score 3):

This is what I managed to do in VS2010 Professional:

Add `Food` as a property of a collection type (I used `ObservableCollection`) to `MealEvent`. Then right-click the property and ***Show as Collection Association***. you will now get a double arrow `--->>` indicating the multiplicty.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this tool but the design seems to be pretty nice. Usually when you work with graphical tools you can either click on the association link to:
- open a contextual menu. 
- to change property into another property view
- to erase it and redo it

You need to change the multiplicity settings and check non navigable option.

Comment: That 1..* was done by me using paint :( I'd like to know how to make it through VS 2010 :(